# Book Store Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, modeling

I'm going to build a book store in which we have 3 entities(classes): Seller,Buyer,Book. I've designed the database as the following details:
- Both buyer and seller can buy/sell one or more books respectively.
- A buyer needs a seller account if he/she wants to sell a book.
- Buyers will offer their price and seller would like to sell to best buyer and I have to save all information among these.

```
In this model the process class will be the other three classes connector:
    seller       book      buyer 
   -------      ------    -------
     sID*        bID*       byID* 
     name  -->   sID     

This was my first thought & then I found out that this schema will fail in the process due to a buyer could buy multiple books at same time and there were other reasons, too. so I changed it:


In this model the process class will be the other three classes connector:
     ______       ______       ________       _______
    |seller|     | book |     |process |     | buyer |
    --------     --------     ----------     ---------
    | sID* |     | bID* |     | pID*   |     | byID* |
    | name |     | XXX  | --> | sID    |  |date &..|
                              ----------
(*) indicates a primary key  


this will work better I think, but how to get into work with Price offers?

yes, I can add a offer to the process class, so I've changed my mind & this model came into the place: (sorry for long description)


The *Offer* field will be added to the *process* class: 
     ______       ______       _________       _______  
    |seller|     | book |     |process  |     | buyer | 
    --------     --------     -----------     ---------  
    | sID* |     | bID* |     |  pID*   |     | byID* |   
    | name |     | XXX  | --> |  sID    |  |  offer  |
                              | date &..|
                              -----------       
(*) indicates a primary key
```

I'm absolutely confused with the db design due to it's my first time.  Is this going to satisfy the system needs?  If no, how can I make it work?  If yes, is there any better design?

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

*update* - I really can't choose the best answer here, all helped. Many many many thanks guys. hope you best ^o^

Comment: Hi artarad - can you explain what you mean by "multiple offers"?

Comment: hihi :) buyers can offer their price to buy the book, so a single book can have just ONE buyer but N offerers.

Answer (score 1):

If a buyer can be a seller (and vice versa), why not have a single customer table with a set of flags for account type?

If books are unique (i.e. one copy of Moby Dick is viewed separate from another copy ... more like eBay than Amazon), then your book table could have a buyer and seller foreign key.  Your store's simplest design is now down to two tables.  For example:

```
Cust table
cust_id
name
is_buyer
is_seller

Book table
book_id
description
seller_cust_id
buyer_cust_id
```

**Edit**:  I don't think this solution changes even if a single buyer/seller must have two accounts.  You would just add the restriction in your app that a customer cannot be both a buyer and seller.  The nice thing about one table is that you don't need to duplicate security/login/etc. logic ...

**Edit 2**:  Also, if a buyer can buy multiple books, wouldn't it make more sense to have a shopping cart table that stores each book purchased by a buyer?

Comment: oh, no! they can't be. a buyer needs to create a seller account if he/she wants to sell somethin'.

Comment: I also disagree. According to the specs, you must have an extra account - where I would make the assumption that an account is atomic and should not share any data with other accounts.

Comment: Sir Lantis, can you expand on what you mean by "account is atomic"? I looked up "Atomicity (database systems)" on Wikipedia, but their definition of atomic is regarding transactions (either "all occur" or "none occur").

Comment: thanks both for the replies. @LucktLindy: the books are unique. what if a book has multiple offers? does ur model work?

Comment: agree with Calvin. I don't know too.

Comment: I meant atomic like in modular - that you can't mess with the internals if you are not inside. If a seller can't "be" a buyer (so says the spec), don't make it possible in the database design. Otherwise you'll need more constraints/integrity checks in DB or SW.

Comment: Better design would be Account(id*, buyer_id, seller_id) + constraint that either must be null, BuyerRole(specific_data), SellerRole(specific_data). Let the other entities link to the roles instead of to the account.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a domain model similar to the following:

```
Buyer(BuyerId, ... buyer details ... )
Seller(SellerId, ... seller details ... )
Book(BookId, ... book details ... )
Bid(BidId, BuyerId, BookId, Price, Expiry)
Offer(OfferId, SellerId, BookId, Price, Expiry
```

How it works is that a user (Buyer or Seller) can create a Bid or Offer as appropriate. So if you are a buyer you may start by searching through the Offers available. If you like one you may choose to accept it and proceed to checkout. Perhaps you don't quite like any of the Offers but one is close in price to what you want. You might create a Bid and have that sent to the creator of the Offer to consider.

Or if nothing is close to your requirements as a buyer you may create a Bid and leave it in the system for potential Sellers to browse/search and consider till time of expiry you have chosen.

I have added the Bid and Offer classes and I think their benefit is self explanatory. But if you would like some further explanation please feel free to leave a comment and I will respond. The Expiry fields are not necessary but most likely every Bid and Offer will have a time limit in which case you will need them.

I have increased the number of classes/tables, but I think you will find that your system becomes much easier to manage and extend.

Comment: The more I look at it the more I realise it can be improved. You really ought to have a single User class and isBuyer/isSeller fields as suggested by LuckLindy, since many buyers will be sellers (as has been pointed out) and you don't want to reproduce data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the buyers will place offers before any seller does anything. Then a seller can accept one of the pending offers.
I would add a buyer ID to the process (in fact, a process would be created when a buyer places an offer), as well as the book ID and the offered price.
Once a seller then closes the deal, the process can be link to the seller with the sID field.
This way a buyer could hold several simultaneous offers on different books.

Comment: that's it, you understood correctly Maurice. so my latest model could work?

Comment: As I said, I would move the offer to the process table, and I would also add a bID and a byID to it

Comment: thanks Maurice, this SO editor sucks, this is not my latest model as you see. many many thanks.

Comment: Do you plan to provide a catalog to the buyers (with info about the book's availability) ?

Comment: Still I don't know, my thought is to remove the book if no copy is available, coz the app will be a store for used books not new ones.

Comment: Then you will need an additional table to link the sellers and the books

Comment: can't I add the seller id to the book field? is it ok in a db design?

Comment: Yes, but in this case, if two sellers have the same book to sell, of if a seller has several copies of the same book to sell, there will be several rows in the book table for the same title. This would introduce redundancy.

Comment: really thanks Maurice, that;s a hard work to consider every aspect of the design :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking LuckyLindy's comment a step further, use a single Customer table, create a table called Order (probably akin to your Process table), and a table called OrderItem.  Your Buyers and Sellers are all Customers ... if your Orders are strictly between two people then your Order table can contain buyer and seller fields.  For each item in an Order, you have a tuple in OrderItem (with an ID back to Order to bind the group).

```
Customer    Order         OrderItem
--------    -----------   ---------
id          id (pk)       id
name        date          order_id (fk)
            buyer (fk)    book
            seller (fk)   price
            total
```

This is really a rudimentary example, but it's shaping up that your requirements could just use a common shopping cart design.  There's lots of [examples you can find by Googling](http://www.phpwebcommerce.com/shopping-cart-database-design.php).

Answer (score 0):

Well, accoring to the specification I would make a few assumptions:

- Buyers and Sellers need seperate accounts - so they *have to* be atomic and must not share data, hence we will have two tables.
- A book is a real-world instance. So, if a seller wants to sell 3 books of "The Hobbit", that would result in 3 table-rows.
- Hence the book might get to attributes: the `seller` (read-only) and the `buyer`. But this doesn't work with the "process" of waiting for incoming offers from buyers.
- Since there might be "batches" of book-buyings it makes sense to create a `AuctionProcess` entity. Also I would add another `Bid` entity. This results in the following scheme.

  ```
  Seller(id*)
  Buyer(id*)
  Book(id*, seller_id)
  AuctionProcess(id*, book_id, winning_bid_id, end_date, start_date?)
  Bid(id*, process_id, buyer_id, price)
  ```

  `winning_bid_id` will of course be `NULL` until  a winner is chosen by the buyer.

It is quite similar to (just noticed) Ankur's response, only with the addition of the `winning_bid_id` relation.

Comment: thank you again. I really can't choose the best answer here, all helped.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem a bit confusing, the datamodel, the object model, functional and non-functional specs and requirements - parts of each being being discussed. Keep the notation and design elements clean, clear and separate.